# Create Two different Checkout form woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create two diff, checkout form

1. For Users
2. Advertiser

Both checkout form contain diff. option. but I can't figure out how to make a separate checkout form for both.

I need solution please if any one have. (Also you can suggest that direct payment to getway skipping checkout it self for specific product)

Comment: You can create a specific user role "advertiser"… so advertisers will have this role additionally. This way you should not need to have 2 different forms, but only one with different options based on user roles condition... `if( current_user_can( 'advertiser' ) ){ // for advertiser } else { // for customer or not logged-in users }`

Comment: No they are not yet register to my website, I need to create a checkout registration form for both, Currently they are guest uses